# AngularJS $resource multiple optional parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have a webservice that allows me to get search results:

```
http://url/api/search/?params
```

Possible parameters to use are: name, location and age
They can be used in any order and combination (they are optional) and are case insensitive (parameters and values)

example:

```
http://url/api/search/?aGe=15&NaME=jOE THomaS&LOCatioN=BElgIUm
```

I have no idea how to setup my $resource correctly to get this working.
Obviously, all the possibilities are GET methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call it directly since they're query params.

```
 angular.module('app').factory('MyService', ['$resource', '$window',function ($resource, $window) {
        'use strict';
        return $resource('http://url/api/search/');
    }]);
```

Then call it like this

```
$scope.result = MyService.get({age: 'foo', location: 'bar'}, 
                       function success() {// success handler here}, 
                       function fail(resp) {// failure handler here});
```

Comment: The fact that I can just use them, is very pleasing. But how can I implement the search in a $httpBackend mock resource?